# Geometric series in a topological ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-series, topological-rings

Let $R$ be a topological ring and $q \in R$ be an element such that $1-q$ is invertible. Does it follow that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^n$ converge? In this case, it would clearly converge to $(1-q)^{-1}$, so the question is equivalent to: Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^n$ converge to $ (1-q)^{-1}$?

Usually in topological rings one encounters the following situation: One wants to show that a certain element $1-q$ *is* invertible. When one knows that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^n$ converges, for example when $R$ is complete with respect to the $I$-adic topology for some ideal $I$ containing $q$, then it follows that this series provides an inverse to $1-q$. So my question is, in some sense, the converse of this.

Comment: It doesn't even work when $R=\mathbb R$. If you add some condition for $q^n\to 0$, you might get better luck.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Right. If $q^n \to 0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^k - (1-q)^{-1} = (1-q^{n+1})(1-q)^{-1} - (1-q)^{-1} = -q^{n+1} (1-q)^{-1} \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider some topological fields such as $\Bbb R$ and $q=2$

Comment: Thank you. So my question was very dumb ...

Comment: @HeinrichD No.

Comment: @HeinrichD, it isn't a stupid question at all. It really depends on what metric you've put on your ring. For example, if you had said $\Bbb{Q},$ with the $2-$adic metric, then the sequence $a_n=2^n$ does converge. . .

Comment: @Chickenmancer: This is the other direction which I have discussed in the second paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 2):

It converges if you can prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}q^n=0$, because of the formula
$$(1-q)^{-1}=1+q+\dots+q^{n-1}+(1-q)^{-1}q^n.$$

Comment: This is an interesting way to "correct" the question.